# SQL join with 2 columns with same name

Tags: sql, join, mariadb

I have created this query:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  arrangement, booker
    WHERE  arrangement.arrangement_id = booker.arrangement_id
      AND  arrangement.dato BETWEEN '2017-09-29' AND '2017-14-10'
      AND  booker.dato > '2017-22-09 18:31:53'
      AND  arrangement.remind = '0'
```

Both arrangement and booker has a field called 'dato'. I try to use the 'dato' from booker as parameter.

I select 'arrrangement.dato between' that works fine
then I select 'booker.dato <'

However, the 'booker.dato <' fails and run in arrangement.dato when executing the query. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: booker.dato > '2017-22-09 18:31:53' - have tested that it works when using only the booker table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use JOIN keyword with ON clause